# Display Progress Label while fetching data

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is how I am trying to do:

```
 void Fetch()
    {
        //Code To Fetch Data        
    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblSatus.Text = "Fetching Data...";
        Thread t = new Thread(Fetch);
        t.Start();           
        t.Join();
        lblSatus.Text = "Got Data";
    }
```

But on click of button it directly display GotData.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: This could be a good post to read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After the `t.Start();` you need something that does a check ...along the lines of:

```
while (!t.Completed) // pseudo
{
    // wait
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

Otherwise, the thread spins up and begins execution while the Main thread simply falls through.

Comment: He has `Join()` in there, which will do the same thing.

Comment: True ...but this will give the OP a way to perform other functions within the `while` that you cannot perform with a `Join()` ...and right now, the OP needs to do some debugging on the Fetch method. Not much else we could really help with on this portion of code ...IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the relationship between threads on the server-side when processing an ASP.NET request, and the experience on the browser-side.  Specifically, for a given HttpRequest (in your example, the Request is a postback, which triggers the btn_Click event), there will be one and only one Response.  This is true, regardless of what thread-manipulation you're doing on the server-side.

In your example, it looks like you're expecting the server to respond to the browser, with lblSatus's value as "Fetching data...".  Then a little later when the operation has completed, the server would "respond" to the browser again, with lblSatus's value as "Got Data".  This will not work, due to the "handshake" nature of Http communication: one request will result in one response (and thus, only one value for lblSatus).

The thing you're trying to do (give the end user a logical "progress bar" during a long-running operation) is a common requirement.  Unfortunately, I know of no easy built-in way to do this in ASP.NET.  I suspect most people do it via a polling model: the browser initiates the action, the server kicks it off in some sort of asynchronous fashion that does NOT delay the response being sent back to the browser.  Then the browser periodically (via javascript, most likely) reaches back to the server to get an update on the operation's progress.